# Single-sided and double-sided concentration inequality

Tags: inequality, machine-learning

### Problem

In statistical learning theory, people are interested to bound something like $P[\vert X-\mathbb{E}[X]\vert\geq t]$ and this is done by
$$
P[\vert X-\mathbb{E}[X]\vert\geq t]\leq 
P[X-\mathbb{E}[X]\geq t]+
P[X-\mathbb{E}[X]\leq -t]
\tag{1}
$$

Now if I could bound individual terms with $\exp(-2nt^2)$, i.e. 
\begin{align}
P[X-\mathbb{E}[X]\geq t]\leq\exp(-2nt^2)\tag{2}\\
P[X-\mathbb{E}[X]\leq -t]\leq\exp(-2nt^2)\tag{3}
\end{align}

By (1), I have
$$
P[\vert X-\mathbb{E}[X]\vert\geq t] \leq 2\exp(-2nt^2)\tag{4}
$$

Now if I set RHS of (2), (3) with $\frac{\delta}{2}$ and RHS of (1) with $\delta$, I have
\begin{align}
 X-\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log \frac{2}{\delta}} \
 (\text{with probability at least}\ \frac{\delta}{2})\tag{5}\\
 X-\mathbb{E}[X] \geq -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log \frac{2}{\delta}} \
 (\text{with probability at least}\ \frac{\delta}{2})\tag{6}\\
 \vert X-\mathbb{E}[X]\vert \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log \frac{1}{\delta}} \ (\text{with probability at least} \ \delta)\tag{7}
\end{align}

I am confused with inequality (5), (6) and (7), which *should be* (but does not seem to be) equivalent by derivation from (1) through (4). Specifically, for (7), could I say
with probability at least $\delta$, the following **simultaneously** hold?

$$
 X-\mathbb{E}[X] \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log \frac{1}{\delta}} \
 (\text{with probability at least}\ \delta)\\
 X-\mathbb{E}[X] \geq -\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}\log \frac{1}{\delta}} \
 (\text{with probability at least}\ \delta)\\
$$

Comment: Some typos - (5,6) should say w.p. $\ge \mathbf{1 -} \delta/2,$ similarly (7). In addition, if you'e obtaining (7) from (5,6), the fluctuation should have $\log(2/\delta),$ not $\log(1/\delta).$ As for the final statement, there should be no further probabilities mentioned in brackets in those, since you've already taken care of the randomness. Roughly, you have events $E_1,E_2$, and have argued $P(E_1) \ge 1-\delta/2$ and $P(E_2) \ge 1- \delta/2.$ Thus, $P(E_1 \cap E_2) \ge  1-\delta,$ and the final statement should be "w.p. $\ge 1 - \delta$, the following hold simltaneously: $\cdots$"